# Please explain this convert extension method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods, ienumerable

I'm trying to make sense of the code below, can someone please explain to me (in simple terms) how and what gets converted.        In particular this part is confusing me (this IEnumerable> values)

Code:

```
public static class ConvertExtensions
{
  public static IEnumerable<TTarget> ConvertAll<TSource, TTarget>(this IEnumerable<IConvertModel<TSource, TTarget>> values) => values.Select(value => value.Convert);
}
```

Comment: `(this IEnumerable<IConvertModel<TSource, TTarget>> values)` has nothing to do with "how and what gets converted", it just says that this is an extension method on `IEnumerable<IConvertModel<TSource, TTarget>>`.

Comment: how `IConvertModel` looks?

Comment: {
    public interface IConvertModel<TSource, TTarget>
    {
        TTarget Convert { get; }
    }
}

Comment: Your `IConvertModel` doesn't seem to be converting any value. It's just supplying a value of `TTarget`.

Comment: The method just takes an enumerable of someones interface which has  a source and a target generic parameter and a convert property, there is nothing more to explain really

Comment: Hi it's not my piece of code. I'm just trying to figure out how it works.

Comment: Why do you need to know this, what cant you do, what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's basically, for every value in a collection, call the `T.Convert` function, (where T is the target type) and return another collection of the converted values.

It doesn't DO any conversion, it hands the conversion off to a different function depending on the output type.

It's a shorthand way of doing something like this:

```
var convertedValues = new List<TTarget>();
foreach(var value in values)
{
   var convertedValue = value.Convert();
   convertedValues.Add(convertedValue);
}
return convertedValues;
```

Comment: Thanks that make more sense to me.